# PWA configured with vite-plugin-pwa errors - manifest not found

Tags: vuejs3, vite, progressive-web-apps, vue-pwa

Any suggestion on getting the install prompt of a PWA configured with vite-plugin-pwa using Vue? I do a 'npm run preview' and can see the service worker is configured and running. However, some how tje manifest config file is missing.  For vite-plugin-pwa the manifest is configured inside of vite.config.js. I must have done something incorrect since Lighthose indicates there is no manifest found. I tried adding a reference link inside index.html but that is incorrect for this setup as well. I would like to be able to see the install prompt in both preview and dev mode if possible. Thanks in advance for suggestions.

**Chrome > devtools > Lighthouse > ERROR:**

```
Page has no manifest <link> URL
```

**GitHub Project:**

```
https://github.com/billjenner/Food-App
```

**Suggested Code Index.html:**

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

Comment: Answer that works. This manifest isn't a json file.

'   <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest">'